# What is the difference between "dispute" and "argue"?

Tags: differences, verbs

There were two English teachers who told me different answers. I'm confused. When I want to talk about two persons having different opinions, I have to say that "they dispute with each other" or "they argue with each other." One of my teachers said we didn't use *dispute* with people, but we use this word for politics and law. Another teacher gave me the following examples while we are learning the S.A.T. word *dispute*:

> - They got into a dispute over the phone bill.
> - She will dispute any suggestion you make, because she doesn't like you.

Are the teachers right? Can I use *dispute* when I want to talk about people?

Answer (score 7):

Both the teachers are correct, in different situations.  You cannot *dispute with* someone, but you can get into *a dispute* with them, or you can *argue with* them.

> Bob disputed with Sally over the phone bill.   *(Incorrect)*
>
> Bob argued with Sally over the phone bill.  **(Correct)**
>
> Bob and Sally got into a dispute over the phone bill.  **(Correct)**

You can use *dispute* as a verb when you're talking about inanimate objects (including but not limited to law or politics), but it doesn't make sense to use when the object is another person.

> Bob disputed the false charges on his phone bill.  **(Correct)**
>
> Bob disputed Sally about the dinner plans.  *(Incorrect)*

Last but not least, there are cases where it may look like the object is a person, but really it's a person's idea or position (ideas being inanimate objects).

> Bob disputed Sally's belief that the Earth was flat.  **(Correct)**

Answer (score 1):

All of the following are correct:

> Bob disputed with Sally about/over the phone bill.
>   Bob argued with Sally over the phone bill.
>   Bob disputed the phone bill.
>   Bob argued with Sally about/over the phone bill.
>   Bob and Sally were at variance about the phone bill.
>   Bob and Sally had discrepant ideas about the phone bill.
>   Bob contested the phone bill.
>   Bob and Sally were at odds about/over the phone bill.
>   Bob and Sally disagreed about the phone bill.

Comment: +1 for _at variance_. Note to the O.P.: that's not a common way of expressing it, but it's definitely a quaint way to say it. _At variance_ might be especially useful if you wanted to emphasize that the dispute was trivial and light, as opposed to, say, an angry shouting match.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DISPUTE vs. ARGUE:
```

Interestingly, "dispute" can serve as a 
noun or verb, as in:

We settled the dispute in arbitration.
   Sir, I dispute your research.

"Argue"(a verb) means, in part, to dispute(!)
another person's claims, logic, opinions,
conclusions, and more.  The verb's
connotation indicates a heated exchange, while 
its cognate, "argument", is a noun which may
or may not connote a heated exchange.
Examples:

His argument was logical, concise, and
   quite persuasive. (not heated)

An argument broke out between the 
   debaters.  (heated--likely)

"Dispute"(as a noun), on the other hand,
denotes a disagreement, which may or may not 
be heated.  In a civil suit, for example,
strong feelings may be involved, but its
purpose is to resolve the dispute in a
calm, reasonable way.  The lawyer
for the defendant marshals his arguments
supporting his client's innocence, while
the lawyer for the plaintiff disputes(as a 
verb) the opposing lawyer's arguments by 
objecting to them and/or by crafting her own 
arguments supporting her client's 
claims.  A judge and/or jury decides
who wins or loses the dispute.

In short, to argue is to disagree sharply 
with someone, whereas to dispute is to take 
exception to someone's point of view, 
conclusion, or rights.  Examples :

Jim and I argued about the money I lent him.

Jim disputed my claim that the money I
   lent him was a loan.

Fred argued against my claim that he
   owed me money.

Your disputing my claim is simply out of
   line and entirely unfair.

Her argument distilled her main points in
   a few well-chosen words.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've never taken money from you in my life.  And even if I did you gave it to me on my birthday, how was I supposed to know it was only a loan?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the first, if rather obvious, thing to say is that *dispute* can function as a verb and a noun, but *argue* can only ever be a verb. The noun from *argue* is *argument*.

The answer to the basic question is that as an intransitive verb *dispute* can be used of people, with the sense, in the Oxford English Dictionary’s definition of:

> To contend with opposing arguments or assertions; to debate or
>   discourse argumentatively; to discuss, argue, hold disputation; often,
>   to debate in a vehement manner or with altercation about something.